# Python Pandas - pandas Missing required dependencies ['numpy']

Tags: pandas, numpy, dependencies

I updated conda with "conda update conda", but after update i started to fail "import pandas as pd" with error message pandas 
Missing required dependencies ['numpy']
Working with pandas 0.19.0
Can anyone supply solution? Thank you
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall Anaconda solved an issue